# Converting Cartesian Coordinates To Polar Coordinates - Matlab

Tags: matlab, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I'm having a problem throughout the conversion process of converting Cartesian to Polar, then back to Cartesian in order to confirm that my initial conversion was successful.

But, for some reason when I am converting back to Cartesian coordinates with Polar coordinates from the third quadrant, my `x` and `y` values are the wrong way around.

Take this part of my code for instance:

```
x = -2.075548439;
y = -2.481775416;

if x < 0 && y < 0 % QUAD 3

    radius = sqrt( (x^2) + (y^2) );
    theta = atand( (y*-1)/(x*-1) );
    theta = (270 - theta);
end

x = radius * cosd(theta); 
y = radius * sind(theta);

% answer: x = -2.481775416, and y = -2.075548439
```

All other `x` and `y` conversions that fall within the other three quadrants put `x` and `y` back in the correct order.

This part of the code, however, does put `x` and `y` back in the correct order:

```
x = 3.130287009;
y = -0.50613326;

if x > 0 && y < 0 % QUAD 4

    radius = sqrt( (x^2) + (y^2) );
    theta = atand( (y*-1)/(x) );
    theta = (360 - theta);
end

x = radius * cosd(theta); 
y = radius * sind(theta);

% answer: x = 3.130287009, and y = -0.50613326
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check for special cases. The following code correctly converts from Cartesian to Polar for points in any quadrant.

```
x = -2.075548439;
y = -2.481775416;

radius = sqrt( (x^2) + (y^2) );
theta = atan2d( y, x );

x = radius * cosd(theta); 
y = radius * sind(theta);
```

Comment: And more easily, `help cart2pol`, `help pol2cart`, unless it is his assignment.

Comment: Thanks, that worked well and shortened my script immensely!  The only thing I had to do was subtract the negative angles from 360 to obtain positive angles once copied and pasted into Excel to match the rest of my data.